# Java code working on IDE but not working in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have written a simple code to fetch response from a server. It works fine on IntelliJ Idea IDE and returns the expected results. The code :

```
import sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.json.JsonParser;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainCode {

    public static void main(String... args){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        Integer result = 0;
        Integer statusCode = 50;
        String response="";
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/Customers/getAllCustomers.php");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode ==  200) {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
//                    parseResult(response);
                result = 1; // Successful
            }else{
                result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
        }
        System.out.print(response);
    }
    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            result += line;
        }

            /* Close Stream */
        if(null!=inputStream){
            inputStream.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

However when i copy and paste this code to android studio, this code stops working. In my observation the try block is never executed as the statusCode output shows 50 when i assign it to a textView. Here is the android studio code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(callThis());
    }

    private static String callThis(){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        Integer result = 0;
        Integer statusCode = 50;
        String response="";
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/Customers/getAllCustomers.php");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode ==  200) {
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
//                    parseResult(response);
                result = 1; // Successful
            }else{
                result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
        }
        return statusCode+response;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            result += line;
        }

            /* Close Stream */
        if(null!=inputStream){
            inputStream.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**UPDATED CODE: Used AsyncTask**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "Http Connection";
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        new AsyncHttpTask().execute();
    }

    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            Integer result = 0;
            String response="";
            int statusCode = 10;
            try {
                /* forming th java.net.URL object */
                URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/Customers/getAllCustomers.php");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
                if (statusCode ==  200) {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    result = 1; // Successful
                }else{
                    result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return response + statusCode; //"Failed to fetch data!";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            /* Download complete. Update UI */
            textView.setText(result);
        }
    }


    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = "";
        String result = "";

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            result += line;
        }

            /* Close Stream */
        if(null!=inputStream){
            inputStream.close();
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
08-13 21:11:21.898    1233-2167/? V/WindowManager﹕ Adding window Window{bd59a00 u0 com.cheatsheet.servercheck/com.cheatsheet.servercheck.MainActivity} at 2 of 6 (before Window{18c764e7 u0 Starting com.cheatsheet.servercheck})
08-13 21:11:21.904    2453-2468/? D/Http Connection﹕ failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
08-13 21:11:21.945    2453-2469/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb43e0130, tid 2469
08-13 21:11:21.958    2453-2469/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-13 21:11:21.995    2453-2469/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-13 21:11:22.015    2453-2469/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-13 21:11:22.015    2453-2469/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43cd940, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-13 21:11:22.667    1233-1256/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.cheatsheet.servercheck/.MainActivity: +950ms
```

Comment: That is what happens when one catches an `Exception e` and doesn't care about it

Comment: @dotvav if the try block was being executed, wouldn't the statusCode change accordingly?

Comment: not if the exception is thrown **before** you assign `statusCode` a value.

Comment: It also appears that you are running network code on the main thread

Comment: It will be not working on Main thread.

Comment: @dieter_h what do you mean? How is it not running on the main thread?

Comment: You are running network code on the main thread. Android does not allow it. See your logcat errors...

Comment: Network call on main thread in Android, not possible. Use `AsyncTask`

Comment: yes i added asynctask, please refer to updated code, but the problem still persists. @Rohit5k2

Comment: @dieter_h i updated the code using asynctask

Comment: http://127.0.0.1 is localhost. Where is your server?

Comment: i am using a wamp server, when i type that link in my browser, i get the required output

Comment: Did you add a permission requirement in your android manifest for INTERNET_ACCESS?

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @natez0r yes i did. found the soln check out my answer :) thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

As i was using 127.0.0.1 to access my server, i couldn't reach it because that was also the ip assigned to my android emulator. So the code worked for java IDE, but didnt work for emulator. I had to replace it with 10.0.2.2 to make it work.